# "Twilight Zone"/"Outer Limits" episode: disfigured bullied boy gets enrolled in an interplanetary exchange program where everyone looks like him

Tags: episode-identification, the-twilight-zone, the-outer-limits

It was back in the sixties or seventies. The story was of a boy with what appears to be a bad head/facial disfigurement.  He's picked on and called a freak by all the kids in the neighborhood.

He wants to live alone or kill himself when he's offered a chance to move to another planet where his deformity wouldn't be noticed as much.  It's an exchange program because the other planet sends their deformed people to us.

The kid from the other planet looks human and considers himself a freak when he looks at his own people. Our boy is surprised when two flight attendants (who have the same look as him) greet him and tell him he's cute.

I try to watch when they do marathons but never seem to find this episode.

Answer (score 15):

Neither one--rather, it was *Night Gallery* (a later show by *Twilight Zone* creator Rod Serling), the episode "The Different Ones" (1971). Plot synopsis [here](https://davidjuhl.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/night-gallery-story-the-different-ones-is-reviewed-here/):

> Paul Koch (Dana Andrews, too stiff and too old-looking for this role) is at his wits’ end trying to figure out what the best plan of action is for his son Victor (Jon Korkes), who suffers from a congenital facial deformity which has caused him to be an outcast and the target of taunts from neighborhood children.
>
> .... Just as Paul is about to trudge out of her office with no alternatives, the official receives a phone call. An inter-planetary exchange program has been brought to her attention. The planet Boreon is looking to recruit people to boost its population and they have no restrictions on the appearance of its immigrants.
>
> ... When Vic arrives on the planet Boreon, a “normal-looking” young man stops to talk for a moment as he passes by. He is leaving on the return ship to earth because he doesn’t fit in on Boreon. Then the welcoming committee arrives: a group of giggling young women who all have the same facial deformity as Vic’s.
>
> No longer morose, Vic says, “I think I’ll be very happy here. I feel as if I belong,” as he walks off arm in arm with the women, who obviously find him attractive.

Comment: Thank you. That episode has been bugging me for quite a while.

Comment: @mapone If this answers your question, please accept the answer using the checkmark on the left, just below the up/down voting buttons.